# ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential_41" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 70, 23, 1), found shape=(None, 23, 1)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

**The X_train shape is 70,23,1**
When i fit my model a have a vallueError:"Input 0 of layer "sequential_41" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 70, 23, 1), found shape=(None, 23, 1)"

```
import tensorflow.keras as keras

input_shape=(X_train.shape[0],X_train.shape[1],X_train.shape[2])
model=keras.Sequential() 
#first layer
model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(32,(3,3),activation='relu',input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(keras.layers.MaxPool2D((3,3),strides=(2,2),padding='same'))
model.add(keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
#second layer
model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(32,(3,3),activation='relu',input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(keras.layers.MaxPool2D((3,3),strides=(2,2),padding='same'))
model.add(keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
#third layer
model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(32,(2,2),activation='relu',input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(keras.layers.MaxPool2D((2,2),strides=(2,2),padding='same'))
model.add(keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
#flatten
model.add(keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(64,activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.3))
#output
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(3,activation='softmax')) #here i created the layers

    #compile
optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",metrics=['accuracy'])`

    model.fit(X_train,y_train,validation_data=(X_validation,y_validation),batch_size=32,epochs=50)
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with your input_shape

**Working sample code**

```
import tensorflow.keras as keras
from tensorflow.keras import datasets

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = datasets.cifar10.load_data()

train_images, test_images = train_images / 255.0, test_images / 255.0

#input_shape=(X_train.shape[0],X_train.shape[1],X_train.shape[2])
input_shape = (32, 32, 3)
model=keras.Sequential() 
#first layer
model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(32,(3,3),activation='relu',input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(keras.layers.MaxPool2D((3,3),strides=(2,2),padding='same'))
model.add(keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
#second layer
model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(32,(3,3),activation='relu',input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(keras.layers.MaxPool2D((3,3),strides=(2,2),padding='same'))
model.add(keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
#third layer
model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(32,(2,2),activation='relu',input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(keras.layers.MaxPool2D((2,2),strides=(2,2),padding='same'))
model.add(keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
#flatten
model.add(keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(64,activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.3))
#output
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(10,activation='softmax')) #here i created the layers

#compile
optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(train_images,train_labels,validation_data=(test_images,test_labels),batch_size=32,epochs=50)
```

**Output**

```
Downloading data from https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar-10-python.tar.gz
170500096/170498071 [==============================] - 3s 0us/step
170508288/170498071 [==============================] - 3s 0us/step
Epoch 1/50
1563/1563 [==============================] - 30s 10ms/step - loss: 1.9637 - accuracy: 0.3127 - val_loss: 1.4890 - val_accuracy: 0.4686
Epoch 2/50
1563/1563 [==============================] - 15s 10ms/step - loss: 1.5202 - accuracy: 0.4551 - val_loss: 1.2940 - val_accuracy: 0.5392
Epoch 3/50
1563/1563 [==============================] - 14s 9ms/step - loss: 1.3549 - accuracy: 0.5159 - val_loss: 1.2059 - val_accuracy: 0.5652
Epoch 4/50
1563/1563 [==============================] - 15s 10ms/step - loss: 1.2629 - accuracy: 0.5535 - val_loss: 1.1335 - val_accuracy: 0.5969
Epoch 5/50
1563/1563 [==============================] - 14s 9ms/step - loss: 1.1955 - accuracy: 0.5757 - val_loss: 1.1059 - val_accuracy: 0.6020
Epoch 6/50
1563/1563 [==============================] - 15s 9ms/step - loss: 1.1358 - accuracy: 0.5989 - val_loss: 1.1843 - val_accuracy: 0.5740
Epoch 7/50
1563/1563 [==============================] - 16s 10ms/step - loss: 1.0994 - accuracy: 0.6098 - val_loss: 1.0681 - val_accuracy: 0.6238
Epoch 8/50
1563/1563 [==============================] - 14s 9ms/step - loss: 1.0607 - accuracy: 0.6235 - val_loss: 1.0812 - val_accuracy: 0.6105
Epoch 9/50
1563/1563 [==============================] - 14s 9ms/step - loss: 1.0317 - accuracy: 0.6354 - val_loss: 1.0024 - val_accuracy: 0.6454
Epoch 10/50
1563/1563 [==============================] - 14s 9ms/step - loss: 1.0056 - accuracy: 0.6439 - val_loss: 0.9617 - val_accuracy: 0.6633
Epoch 11/50
1563/1563 [==============================] - 15s 10ms/step - loss: 0.9846 - accuracy: 0.6524 - val_loss: 0.9767 - val_accuracy: 0.6567
Epoch 12/50
1563/1563 [==============================] - 16s 10ms/step - loss: 0.9602 - accuracy: 0.6593 - val_loss: 0.9369 - val_accuracy: 0.6690
Epoch 13/50
1563/1563 [==============================] - 18s 12ms/step - loss: 0.9412 - accuracy: 0.6681 - val_loss: 0.9222 - val_accuracy: 0.6755
Epoch 14/50
1563/1563 [==============================] - 17s 11ms/step - loss: 0.9220 - accuracy: 0.6749 - val_loss: 0.9370 - val_accuracy: 0.6661
Epoch 15/50
1563/1563 [==============================] - 15s 10ms/step - loss: 0.9083 - accuracy: 0.6786 - val_loss: 0.9255 - val_accuracy: 0.6743
Epoch 16/50
1563/1563 [==============================] - 15s 9ms/step - loss: 0.8930 - accuracy: 0.6845 - val_loss: 0.9464 - val_accuracy: 0.6643
Epoch 17/50
1563/1563 [==============================] - 14s 9ms/step - loss: 0.8807 - accuracy: 0.6895 - val_loss: 0.9692 - val_accuracy: 0.6584
Epoch 18/50
1563/1563 [==============================] - 16s 10ms/step - loss: 0.8630 - accuracy: 0.6946 - val_loss: 0.8778 - val_accuracy: 0.6918
Epoch 19/50
1563/1563 [==============================] - 15s 10ms/step - loss: 0.8563 - accuracy: 0.6986 - val_loss: 0.9169 - val_accuracy: 0.6827
Epoch 20/50
1563/1563 [==============================] - 14s 9ms/step - loss: 0.8373 - accuracy: 0.7047 - val_loss: 0.8914 - val_accuracy: 0.6849
Epoch 21/50
1563/1563 [==============================] - 11s 7ms/step - loss: 0.8317 - accuracy: 0.7063 - val_loss: 0.8581 - val_accuracy: 0.6975
Epoch 22/50
1563/1563 [==============================] - 11s 7ms/step - loss: 0.8209 - accuracy: 0.7129 - val_loss: 0.8576 - val_accuracy: 0.6969
Epoch 23/50
1563/1563 [==============================] - 11s 7ms/step - loss: 0.8102 - accuracy: 0.7136 - val_loss: 0.8521 - val_accuracy: 0.7038
Epoch 24/50
1563/1563 [==============================] - 11s 7ms/step - loss: 0.8044 - accuracy: 0.7156 - val_loss: 0.8357 - val_accuracy: 0.7087
Epoch 25/50
1563/1563 [==============================] - 11s 7ms/step - loss: 0.7946 - accuracy: 0.7184 - val_loss: 0.8323 - val_accuracy: 0.7068
Epoch 26/50
1563/1563 [==============================] - 11s 7ms/step - loss: 0.7879 - accuracy: 0.7214 - val_loss: 0.8405 - val_accuracy: 0.7039
Epoch 27/50
1563/1563 [==============================] - 11s 7ms/step - loss: 0.7827 - accuracy: 0.7239 - val_loss: 0.8806 - val_accuracy: 0.6975
Epoch 28/50
1563/1563 [==============================] - 11s 7ms/step - loss: 0.7730 - accuracy: 0.7262 - val_loss: 0.8072 - val_accuracy: 0.7137
Epoch 29/50
1563/1563 [==============================] - 11s 7ms/step - loss: 0.7655 - accuracy: 0.7301 - val_loss: 0.8129 - val_accuracy: 0.7163
Epoch 30/50
1563/1563 [==============================] - 11s 7ms/step - loss: 0.7570 - accuracy: 0.7321 - val_loss: 0.9301 - val_accuracy: 0.6773
Epoch 31/50
1563/1563 [==============================] - 11s 7ms/step - loss: 0.7530 - accuracy: 0.7335 - val_loss: 0.8197 - val_accuracy: 0.7164
Epoch 32/50
1563/1563 [==============================] - 11s 7ms/step - loss: 0.7425 - accuracy: 0.7385 - val_loss: 0.8179 - val_accuracy: 0.7160
Epoch 33/50
1563/1563 [==============================] - 11s 7ms/step - loss: 0.7380 - accuracy: 0.7398 - val_loss: 0.8029 - val_accuracy: 0.7195
Epoch 34/50
1563/1563 [==============================] - 11s 7ms/step - loss: 0.7291 - accuracy: 0.7439 - val_loss: 0.8062 - val_accuracy: 0.7230
Epoch 35/50
1563/1563 [==============================] - 11s 7ms/step - loss: 0.7220 - accuracy: 0.7451 - val_loss: 0.8037 - val_accuracy: 0.7220
Epoch 36/50
1563/1563 [==============================] - 11s 7ms/step - loss: 0.7186 - accuracy: 0.7454 - val_loss: 0.9138 - val_accuracy: 0.6886
Epoch 37/50
1563/1563 [==============================] - 11s 7ms/step - loss: 0.7147 - accuracy: 0.7489 - val_loss: 0.8109 - val_accuracy: 0.7188
Epoch 38/50
1563/1563 [==============================] - 11s 7ms/step - loss: 0.7111 - accuracy: 0.7504 - val_loss: 0.7770 - val_accuracy: 0.7300
Epoch 39/50
1563/1563 [==============================] - 11s 7ms/step - loss: 0.7081 - accuracy: 0.7502 - val_loss: 0.7844 - val_accuracy: 0.7279
Epoch 40/50
1563/1563 [==============================] - 11s 7ms/step - loss: 0.7027 - accuracy: 0.7517 - val_loss: 0.8060 - val_accuracy: 0.7191
Epoch 41/50
1563/1563 [==============================] - 11s 7ms/step - loss: 0.6943 - accuracy: 0.7546 - val_loss: 0.8224 - val_accuracy: 0.7210
Epoch 42/50
1563/1563 [==============================] - 11s 7ms/step - loss: 0.6901 - accuracy: 0.7565 - val_loss: 0.8355 - val_accuracy: 0.7110
Epoch 43/50
1563/1563 [==============================] - 11s 7ms/step - loss: 0.6843 - accuracy: 0.7581 - val_loss: 0.8174 - val_accuracy: 0.7170
Epoch 44/50
1563/1563 [==============================] - 11s 7ms/step - loss: 0.6831 - accuracy: 0.7586 - val_loss: 0.8536 - val_accuracy: 0.7066
Epoch 45/50
1563/1563 [==============================] - 11s 7ms/step - loss: 0.6765 - accuracy: 0.7613 - val_loss: 0.7858 - val_accuracy: 0.7300
Epoch 46/50
1563/1563 [==============================] - 11s 7ms/step - loss: 0.6713 - accuracy: 0.7629 - val_loss: 0.8862 - val_accuracy: 0.7020
Epoch 47/50
1563/1563 [==============================] - 11s 7ms/step - loss: 0.6695 - accuracy: 0.7625 - val_loss: 0.7928 - val_accuracy: 0.7275
Epoch 48/50
1563/1563 [==============================] - 11s 7ms/step - loss: 0.6621 - accuracy: 0.7672 - val_loss: 0.8244 - val_accuracy: 0.7211
Epoch 49/50
1563/1563 [==============================] - 11s 7ms/step - loss: 0.6590 - accuracy: 0.7671 - val_loss: 0.8121 - val_accuracy: 0.7187
Epoch 50/50
1563/1563 [==============================] - 11s 7ms/step - loss: 0.6539 - accuracy: 0.7685 - val_loss: 0.7895 - val_accuracy: 0.7282
<keras.callbacks.History at 0x7ff800564090>
```